# Carrierwave Image Upload & Rails 5 undefined method `map'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, carrierwave

I usually always used Carrierwave with Rails <=4, but am now working on a Rails 5 project. I can't upload images anymore and I am getting multiple errors (Tried in ActiveAdmin (undefined method map and Seed File).
Does anyone know how where the error is?

**Versions used:**

```
Ruby 2.4.1p111
Rails 5.02
Carrierwave 1.1.0
ActiveAdmin from Github Master Repo
```

As usual I generated my Uploaders and mounted them to my model.

**uploaders/StoreImageUploader.rb**

```
class StoreImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [250, 250]
  end

end
```

**models/store.rb**

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploaders :image, StoreImageUploader
  serialize :image, JSON # If you use SQLite, add this line.
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :orders
end
```

Usually ActiveAdmin detects that `mounted uploaders` and sets the `image:string` field to `:file`, automatically, but not this time.

I manually adjusted the active admin file.

**admin/store.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store do
permit_params :name , :image
  form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
    f.inputs "Store" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :image, :as => :file
    end
    f.button "Create"
  end
end
```

**When uploading I get following error:**[image: Active Admin Upload]

Comment: It was a typo error `mount_uploaders`:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, It was a typo error `mount_uploaders`